ASP.NET Core MVC - Radio Button Selection Not Persisting During Edit
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application where users can manage categories. I have a partial view (_AddOrEditModal.cshtml) used for both creating and editing categories. This partial view includes radio buttons to select the category Type (either "Expense" or "Income").
The problem I'm facing is that when editing an existing category, I'm unable to change the selected radio button for the Type property. The radio buttons are displayed correctly according to the current value of Model.Type, but I cannot select the other option at all during editing. For example, if a category is of Type "Expense", the "Expense" radio button is pre-selected, but I cannot click on the "Income" radio button to switch it. It just doesn't react to clicks. Only the value of Model.Name can be changed
Interestingly, an identical form, but placed in a separate full view (instead of a popup / modal), with a separate controller only for the Edit action, works fine. There I can freely change the radio button selection.
Here's the relevant code:
Partial View (_AddOrEditModal.cshtml)
@model LabProject.Models.Category

@{
    string idContent;
    string headingContent;
    string submitContent;

    if (Model.Id == 0) {
        idContent = "AddOrEditModal";
        headingContent = "Create new category";
        submitContent = "Create";
    } 
    else 
    {
        idContent = $"AddOrEditModal-{Model.Id}";
        headingContent = "Edit your category";
        submitContent = "Edit";
    }
}


<div class="modal fade" id="@idContent" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header flex-wrap">
                <h5 class="modal-title mb-3" id="exampleModalLabel2">@headingContent</h5>
                
                <button type="button"
                        class="btn-close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>

                <form id="categoryForm" asp-action="AddOrEdit" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                    
                    <div class="d-flex gap-2 mb-3">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="Type" id="expenseRadio" value="Expense" asp-for="Type"
                         />
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="expenseRadio">
                            Expense
                        </label>
                       
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="Type" id="incomeRadio" value="Income" asp-for="Type"
                         />
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="incomeRadio">
                            Income
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="submit" value="@submitContent" class="btn btn-primary mb-4" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}

Controller (AddOrEdit Action):
// GET: CategoryController/AddOrEdit
public IActionResult AddOrEdit(int? id)
{
    
    if (id == null)
    {                
        return PartialView("_AddOrEditModal", new Category());
    } else
    {
        Category category = _context.Categories.Find(id);
        
        return PartialView("_AddOrEditModal",category);
    }
    
}

// POST: CategoryController/AddOrEdit
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit([Bind("Id,Name,IsDefault, UserId, Type")] Category category)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }

    

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            category.UserId = user.Id.ToString();
            if (category.Id == 0)
            {
                _context.Categories.Add(category);
            }
            else
            {
                _context.Categories.Update(category);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(CategoryList));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMessage"] = $"An error occurred: {ex.Message}";
        }
    }
    var categories = await _context.Categories
        .Where(c => c.UserId == user.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
    //return View("CategoryList", categories);
    return PartialView("_AddOrEditModal", category);
}

The Type property is contained in the [Bind] attribute, and I use asp-for for the radio buttons. However, I can't even select an alternative radio button when editing.
What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

"but I cannot click on the "Income" radio button to switch it. It just doesn't react to clicks."  ---check if it's a css issue and i've show an example below,hopes help

a minimal  example based on your codes that works well on myside:
Model:
public class ViewModel
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get;set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

View:
Index Page:
<button id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Open Modal</button>



<partial name="Partial" model="@new ViewModel()"></partial>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    })

</script>

Partial View:
@model ViewModel


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header flex-wrap">
                <h5 class="modal-title mb-3" id="exampleModalLabel2">Head</h5>

                <button type="button"
                        class="btn-close"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>

                <form id="categoryForm" asp-action="AddOrEdit" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>


                    <div class="d-flex gap-2 mb-3">
                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="Type" id="expenseRadio" value="Expense" asp-for="Type" />
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="expenseRadio">
                            Expense
                        </label>

                        <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="Type" id="incomeRadio" value="Income" asp-for="Type" />
                        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="incomeRadio">
                            Income
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-4" />
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Controller:
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddOrEdit(ViewModel vm)
{
    return Ok();
}

Result:


